# Using Ifstream to create a vector or array, to use the values in the main function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, iostream

I'm trying to input partial file content into an array or a vector of type double, and then compare these variables to find the largest of them.

the file has these:

10003830 2.5
37585765 3.2
47565873 1.9
48577594 2.9
76487649 3.7
38457955 2.9

in student number and gpa format. I only need to compare the gpa and display the gpa and the student number of the student with the highest gpa.

Comment: ...so what have you tried?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using::std::copy;
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
  int ID;
  double GPA;
 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
 double line[20];
 vector<double>fileToVector;
 ifstream readFile;
 Student student;
 readFile.open("file_name.txt");
 if (readFile.fail()){ cout << "File open failed.\n"; exit(1);}
 cout.setf(ios::fixed);
 cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
 readFile.precision(); 
while(readFile >> student.ID >> student.GPA) cout << student.ID << " " << setw(2) << student.GPA << endl; return 0; } –

Comment: while(readFile >> student.ID >> student.GPA)
  cout << student.ID << " " << setw(2) << student.GPA << endl;
  copy
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: @RemoneTurkoglu please add that to your question with the [edit] link below your post

Comment: i can open the file, i do not know how to use a nested for loop to input the info into a vector or an array to compare

Comment: Do you know how to put one object into a vector? When the students are in the vector, do you know how to find the one with the highest GPA?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using::std::copy;
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
  int ID;
  double GPA;
 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 vector<double>fileToVector;
 ifstream readFile;
 Student student;
 
 readFile.open("file_name.txt");
 if (readFile.fail()){ cout << "File open failed.\n"; exit(1);}
 cout.setf(ios::fixed);
 cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
 readFile.precision();
 
 while(readFile >> student.ID >> student.GPA)
 cout << student.ID << " " << setw(2) << student.GPA << endl;
 readFile.close();
 return 0;
}

Comment: Im not sure if im suppose to, create a vector for each line of information from the file.

Comment: No, you should create one `Student` for each line of the file. **You are trying to do too many things at once.** Start with a `vector<int>`, and learn to put numbers into it and iterate over it.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that

Comment: There was not limit set, the program should be able to accept as many of students that file has.